Ubuntu user usage limitation or watchdog
I am maintaining a compute server that runs Ubuntu on bare metal infrastructure and is used by regular users.
We have recently encountered a challenging issue where some users with a lack of basic programming knowledge would mistakenly consume all server resources (CPU and mermory), causing all services, including SSH, to become unresponsive. This makes it difficult to diagnose and recover from the failure remotely.
I would like to get some advice on the following questions:

We are unable to update the infrastructure of our servers, such as implementing virtualization, in the short term. As a workaround, I would like to ensure that certain critical processes, such as SSH and some essential custom management services, always have some resources allocated to them and run with high priority.

I would like to be able to identify and record users who are consuming excessive resources, in order for us to determine the relevant individuals for training purposes.

Due to certain reasons, we are unable to physically access the servers frequently. Therefore, in the worst-case scenario, we are considering if there are any solutions that can act as watchdogs, logging and forcefully restarting the server when it becomes unresponsive.


Thank you for your inquiry and any suggestions you may have.
Regards

If your physical / bare metal server has 'Remote Console' / 'Integrated Lights Out Management' you can use that to restart the server when it become unresponsive.
Also RC / ILOM might be able to show you the server console and logs.
All servers on remote locations / without easy physical access, should be configured with Remote Console, IMHO.

Hi, This seems like a good suggestion, and we have indeed considered it in the past. However, due to specific network management requirements, we are not allowed to expose any web pages. Unfortunately, IPMI login page is also a web page. Thank you for your suugestions.

To manage user usage limitations or set up a watchdog system on Ubuntu, you have a variety of tools and methods at your disposal. These include setting resource limits, monitoring user activity, and imposing specific restrictions. Here are some detailed steps and tools you can use:
1. User Resource Limits with ulimit
ulimit is a shell command used to impose limitations on the resources available to the shell and its child processes.
Example:
Edit the /etc/security/limits.conf file to set resource limits for a specific user:
username  hard  nproc  100
username  hard  nofile  200

This sets the maximum number of processes (nproc) and the maximum number of open files (nofile) for the user username.
2. Cgroups for Resource Control
Control Groups (cgroups) allow you to allocate resources such as CPU, memory, and I/O to specific groups of processes.
Example:

Install cgroup-tools:
sudo apt-get install cgroup-tools


Create a cgroup and set limits:
sudo cgcreate -g cpu,memory:/mygroup
sudo cgset -r memory.limit_in_bytes=500M /mygroup
sudo cgset -r cpu.shares=512 /mygroup


Add a user or process to the cgroup:
sudo cgclassify -g cpu,memory:/mygroup <PID>



3. System Monitoring and Watchdogs
Using psacct
psacct (or acct) is a package of utilities for monitoring user activity.

Install psacct:
sudo apt-get install acct


Start the service:
sudo systemctl start acct
sudo systemctl enable acct


Monitor user activity:

sa: Summary of accounting information.
lastcomm: Information about previously executed commands.
ac: User logins.



Using auditd
auditd is the userspace component of the Linux Auditing System, providing detailed logging of user actions.

Install auditd:
sudo apt-get install auditd


Configure audit rules:
Edit /etc/audit/audit.rules to add rules. For example, to monitor a specific file or directory:
-w /etc/passwd -p wa -k passwd_changes


Start the service:
sudo systemctl start auditd
sudo systemctl enable auditd


View logs:
sudo ausearch -k passwd_changes



4. Using pam_limits
pam_limits is a PAM module that sets limits on system resources for users.

Edit /etc/security/limits.conf:
@groupname hard nproc 100
@groupname hard nofile 200


Ensure PAM uses these limits:
Edit /etc/pam.d/common-session and add:
session required pam_limits.so



5. Custom Scripts and Cron Jobs
You can create custom scripts to monitor and enforce limits and then use cron jobs to execute these scripts periodically.
Example Script:
#!/bin/bash
# Check CPU usage and kill process if it exceeds 80%
CPU_LIMIT=80
for pid in $(pgrep -u username); do
  CPU_USAGE=$(ps -p $pid -o %cpu= | awk '{print int($1)}')
  if [ "$CPU_USAGE" -gt "$CPU_LIMIT" ]; then
    kill -9 $pid
  fi
done

Save this script and create a cron job to run it periodically:
* * * * * /path/to/script.sh

Additional Resources

systemd Resource Control: systemd has built-in support for resource control using systemd.slice units. You can define limits directly in systemd unit files.
LXD/LXC: Containers can be used to limit resource usage for specific applications or users, providing an isolated environment with controlled resource allocation.

By using these methods and tools, you can effectively manage user usage limitations and monitor system activity on your Ubuntu system.
